# Unable to SSH into Ubuntu server, after opening some random ports

Tags: 18.04, ssh, ufw, putty

I just open a port in the server using the below command and suddenly putty connection fails for everyone.

This happens every time when I open a port. I think something is wrong with my command used to open the port.

sudo ufw allow 5700 - I use this for opening any port, I think the syntax is only for opening ssh port and not other ports, Please correct me and in the future, I can use proper syntax

P.S. ssh keys are set to No, password authentication to Yes

Thank you all,

Edit 1:  ufw status output

To                         Action      From

---

4675                       ALLOW       Anywhere

4675/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere

23                         ALLOW       Anywhere

23/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere

8443/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere

22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere

80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere

443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere

11211                      ALLOW       Anywhere

8080/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere

9503/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere

9502/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere

9501/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere

9500/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere

3500/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere

3503/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere

3502/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere

9506/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere

1992/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere

8762/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere

8083/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere

1998/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere

9251/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere

9252/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere

3423/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere

6379                       ALLOW       Anywhere

3282/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere

3000/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere

9238/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere

1991/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere

5550/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere

1993/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere

61616/tcp                  ALLOW       Anywhere

8181/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere

8161/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere

1995/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere

9327/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere

1999/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere

1997/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere

2003/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere

7340/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere

8084/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere

3001/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere

27017/tcp                  ALLOW       Anywhere

7748/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere

5600                       ALLOW       Anywhere

5601                       ALLOW       Anywhere

5601/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere

5600/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere

4675 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

4675/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

23 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

23/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

8443/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

11211 (v6)                 ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

8080/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

9503/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

9502/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

9501/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

9500/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

3500/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

3503/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

3502/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

9506/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

1992/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

8762/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

8083/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

1998/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

9251/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

9252/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

3423/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

6379 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

3282/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

3000/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

9238/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

1991/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

5550/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

1993/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

61616/tcp (v6)             ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

8181/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

8161/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

1995/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

9327/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

1999/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

1997/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

2003/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

7340/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

8084/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

3001/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

27017/tcp (v6)             ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

7748/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

5600 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

5601 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

5601/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

5600/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

Comment: Did you also allow SSH before enabling ufw? Please [edit] your question to show the output of `sudo ufw status`

Comment: yes ssh was allowed before enabling ufw and for e.g., I run sudo ufw allow 5700, that's it ssh to the (GCP)server fails, sometimes need to reboot the server or just wait for 4-5 hrs, and then it works.